# CONCATENATE function for two columns

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

So I have two columns in Excel, A and B. Column A has letters from A - J, and column b has number from 1 - 9. I would like to write a CONCATENATE function that would string each letter in column A with a number in column B. So basically it's going to be A1, A2, ...A9, and then back at B1, B2, ... B9. Is there anyway for me to put this in a macro?

I assume it would be something like this: 
    Dim rngA as Range 
    Dim rngB as Range

but I don't know what I should do next. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What does "and then back at B1, B2, ... B9" mean?

Comment: So I want the CONCATENATE function to match the letter in column A with the number in column B... so it's going to be A1, A2, A3, ...A9, B1, B2, ...B9, C1, C2, ... C9.

Comment: Dane's answer should work then. The & sign concatenates whatever you put either side of it.

Answer (score 0):

No macro is necessary. Assuming the data is in cell A1 and B1, simply place the formula

```
=A1&B1
```

into the desired cell you wish to have the concatenated result be. This can then be dragged down using the lower right hand corner of the cell assuming you would like the entirety of the columns to be concatenated.

Comment: But after Excel has concatenated A1, A2, ... until A10, it won't come back to B1, B2, etc.